# Using Charles Proxy with .NET Core Azure Site - how do I see API call?

Tags: charles-proxy

Hello stack**overflow**

I've built a small application with core.net so I could become familiar with Charles Proxy.

When I run the application locally (Mac Visual Studio 2019 - debug) I can use Charles, set a breakpoint and change the data / mock the data in the API call. **I can of course see the API Endpoint that the code is calling.** :-)

**When I publish the application to Azure I can no longer see the call to the API / endpoint that the code is calling.** :-(

I need to show others on my team how to use Charles and would like to use this Azure site I created to do so. Any help in how to do this would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Met with our test engineers and they said I should run Charles Proxy on Azure.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Breakpoint from Proxyman. Here is a tutorial: https://proxyman.io/blog/2019/09/Use-Breakpoint-to-intercept-and-edit-request-response-on-iOS-app.html